# RequireJS-like framework inside of PHP

Tags: php, module, requirejs

I'm using RequireJS now for a few weeks, and I'm really beginning to like it.

But now I'm wondering if there is something similar for PHP. Currently I do it this way:

```
class someModule implements Module{

    function run($foobar){
        //some code
    }
}
CORE::register('someModule');
```

Note that I want to stay backwards compatible so I cannot use namespaces.

Comment: sounds like you want [class autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) - there is no framework to do this as it's a language feature. Though: there are [established standards](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) on how autoloading can work. (no, you don't need to use namespaces to use class autoloading).

Comment: yes and no, what i really like from requirejs is the automatic dependency loading. for instance if you load the user model you also need to load the connection to the database.

Comment: Then it sounds like you simply need to use "a" php framework - they all do that - or [pimple](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/)